# Wordpress - duplicator plugin back up fail

Tags: php, wordpress, backup, cpanel

I've just moved a wordpress site from localhost to live server and attempted a backup using the duplicator plugin. It's showing the following error/fail -

[image: duplicator fail]

It's also showing a red 'Pass' for 'required paths' with the following comment for three filepaths - *If Duplicator does not have enough permissions then you will need to manually create the paths above.*

I'm using GoDaddy cPanel hosting for the server. Is this a common issue when you move to a live server? If so, how do I resolve it?

Comment: The permissions problem can append with some hosters and need to do a few manipulations. but without Zip support, there may be a solution to unarchive the file manualy but after that you will have to do the same for installing plugins and themes then it's not a good hosting plan for wordpress. ask more informations at the hoster about this Zip library.

Comment: instead of using ZIP archive, you can use DUP archive(archive.daf) for this duplicator plugin.this is another alternative given by the duplicator.

Answer (score 0):

After some studying and assistance from a wordpress forum, the solution was to install an archive_zip extension from the PHP Pearl package section in the cPanel and then click through to the PHP versions section and tick the box next to 'zip'. Hit save and then the backup worked.